# WCF RIA Services Insert Child Items along with New Parent Item

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, ria

Say I have a object called project, and each project has tasks... Lets say I wanted to create a project and specify tasks...Do all this in one form...and when the user clicks 'save', save the project and tasks...However because project does not exist, when I create the tasks, they won't have a pk? How Can I handle this...be able to insert child with new parent...

Thanks,

Malcom

Answer (score 0):

With Linq:

```
Project project = new Project();
project.Tasks = tasks;
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Linq will assign the primary keys and foreign keys.